# Connecting with SignalR after login or Delayed connection with SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am working with SignalR & MVC. The code that i looked up actually connects the user to the hub at startup.

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Uno.Hubs.Startup))]

namespace ChatTBox
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }


}
```

However, i need the user to connect to SignalR after it has successfully logged in and then keep and display the list of connected signed in user. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This call doesn't connect the user to the hub, it simply registers the SignalR  middleware (the same way you would call app.UseWebApi()). Connecting a user is initiated by the client from the client.

You can connect a client after login from the client. The example on asp.net can be modified to suit:

```
// login
// assuming your hub is called ChatTBoxHub
var chatTBoxHubProxy = $.connection.contosoChatHub;
// wire up the event the server can call on the client
chatTBoxHubProxy.client.addMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
    console.log(name + ' ' + message);
};
// start the signalR connection
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    // Wire up Send button to call NewContosoChatMessage on the server.
    chatTBoxHubProxy.server.register(someUniqueClientIdServer);
});

// For .Net clients:
var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://yourUrl/");
IHubProxy chatTBoxHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatTBoxHub");
chatTBoxHubProxy.On<Message>("addMessageToPage", message => Console.WriteLine("Message '{0}' received from {1}", message.Body, message.Name));
await hubConnection.Start();

// EDIT to add example registration in your server hub class
public void Register(string uniqueClientId)
{
    hubUsers[uniqueClientId] = Context.ConnectionId; // Context is supplied by SignalR base class.
}
```

Comment: Ok what i understood that i should create the connection and call it after the user has successfully logged in on portal. But how do i manage calls to individual senders instead of mass broadcasting?

Comment: In your hub class on the server, override the OnConnected, OnDisconnected events, keep a static collection of connection ids against the appropriate user Id. I've used a static dictionary of connection Id to user names for similar purposes. With that in place you add/remove a user using the Context.ConnectionId property in the Hub, which allows you to use the connection Id when sending to a client: Clients.Client(connectionId).addMessageToPage(name, msg).

Comment: @reckface how would he know which user the connection I'd belongs to ? Meaning how does he map the login from the mvc end point to the signalr connection when the connection occured

Comment: @eranotzap I haven't used this in a long time, but you simply add a public method in your hub class `Register(uniqueClientId)` in my example, and call it in the `.done()` callback after start with a uniquely identifying all your clients.